# Get table name from MS Access

Tags: c#, ms-access

I Want to get names of table from Ms Access into List. And I use

```cs
DataTable dt = con.GetSchema("TABLES");

foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
   SelectTable.Add(dr[2].ToString());
}
```

But there are many tables my List. How to get only my Table name?

Comment: Have a look at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15900849/3908810) to View Data from MS Access in Data Grid View

Comment: Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699897/retrieve-list-of-tables-in-ms-access-file

Comment: @StudioX That may or may not be a good idea, because it's not just getting the table names, it's also retrieving all the data.

Comment: I SOLVED this problem Thanks